# Reverse deadline?

Tags: vocabulary, antonyms

Is there a term or word for a "reverse deadline"? Deadline is normally the date or time before which something must occur. I'm seeking a term for the date or time after which something may occur.

I am preparing instructions for announcing results which must be announced after a certain date. At the moment the text proposes to use the word 'deadline', but for the reasons mentioned above I will propose to reword it to "Results cannot be announced before..." but I would prefer to use a 'deadline'-type word instead.

Comment: What is the context, what does the date represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally this is described in text as ***embargoed*** until the time in question. [ODO on *embargo*.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/embargo)

You could usefully call the time itself (analogous to deadline) the *release time*.

Comment: Based on this answer I will go with one of the following: _release date_, _announcement date_ or _results date_.